# How to "not reject" an incoming call during do not disturb?

Tags: iphone, ios

The *Do Not Disturb* feature in iOS 6 is great but i really dont like the part where it rejects the incoming call. Is it possible to just let it ring (without notification or sound)?

Is there a tweak in cydia that can change the way *Do Not Disturb* behaves? I have suspended using this feature because many people confuse this with me not wanting to pick up their call (rejecting).

Comment: Would you kindly mark Ryccardo's post as an answer since you have accepted his response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No jailbreak needed, just set the option found in **Preferences/Notifications/Do Not Disturb/Allow calls from** to **Everyone**.

Comment: This may be a workaround. Perhaps the OP wants to not hear calls (the way it is normally with DND - no vibration or audible alerts), but, like he said, let them ring?

Comment: Thanks bassplayer, you hit the nail on the head. I exactly want that !

Comment: It appears that RingerX VIP has a feature that, although not exactly fitting your request, might be helpful: http://cydiablog.gdnainc.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/RingerX-VIP-2.png

Answer (score 2):

You can already silence incoming calls without rejecting them by turning on the **Mute** switch on the side of your iPhone. Then go into **Settings** → **Sounds & Haptics** and *Disable* `Vibrate on Silent`.

You can combine this with **Do Not Disturb** by allowing calls from `Everyone` under **Settings** → **Do Not Disturb**.

You will still get the Incoming Call screen, as the only way to make it go away is to either accept or reject the call (from a UI perspective, there’s no reason to have a call ring that you cannot accept). However if you’re not using your iPhone at that time then this achieves your purpose of letting your callers go to voicemail “naturally,” rather than after one ring.