# How can my iPhone ring only from favorites, but silence from others?

Tags: iphone, do-not-disturb

Most Android phones have such a feature.

iPhone's "Do Not Disturb" works, but just mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87490) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7451591), it rejects all others instead of keeping silent.

Comment: a silent ringtone (not on iphone by default) is not an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can already silence incoming calls without rejecting them by turning on the Mute switch (on/off switch, not volume control) on the left side of your iPhone.
Then:

1. Edit a contact
2. Select "Ringtone"
3. Enable "Emergency Bypass"

Emergency bypass allows sounds and vibrations from this person even when the ring switch is set to silent or when Do Not Disturb is on.